# Assign value to wrapper throw null exception

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

I have a JSON String Need to pass as request body with configurabale parameter as below.I have used a wrapper class for that called as **EmailWrapper** , but here assign value to  wrapper.options.fieldOne ,throw Attempt to de-reference a null object but threatMapping.Field1__c has value. I think I have access wrapper in incorrect way. Can someone help me on this?

```
public with sharing class TestValid {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void emailValidation(String email){
        EmailOptionAttributes emailOptions = new EmailOptionAttributes();
        EmailWrapper wrapper = new EmailWrapper();
        System.debug('email====-: ' +email);
        if(email != null){
            System.debug('email====-: ' +email);
            wrapper.emailValue = email;
            System.debug('email2====-: ' +email);
        }
        Email_validation__mdt[] emailValidation = [SELECT Field1__c,Field2__c,Field3__c,Field4__c,Field5__c FROM Email_validation__mdt];
        System.debug('emailValidation' +emailValidation);
        for (Email_validation__mdt threatMapping : emailValidation) {
            wrapper.options.fieldOne = threatMapping.Field1__c;
            wrapper.options.fieldTwo = threatMapping.Field2__c;
            wrapper.options.fieldThree =  threatMapping.Field3__c;
            wrapper.options.fieldFour = threatMapping.Field4__c;
            wrapper.options.fieldFive = threatMapping.Field5__c;
        }
        System.debug('emailOptions: ' +emailOptions);
        String jsonString = JSON.serialize(emailOptions);
        System.debug('jsonString: ' +jsonString);

    }

    public class EmailOptionAttributes {
        public  Boolean fieldOne;
        public  Boolean fieldTwo;
        public  Boolean fieldThree;
        public  Boolean fieldFour;
        public  Boolean fieldFive;
    }

    public class EmailWrapper{
        public String emailValue;
        public EmailOptionAttributes options;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to assign `wrapper.options = emailOptions` before you try to set the option field values.

Comment: BTW, only the last MDT's values will be kept with the way you wrote this code.

Comment: Thank you for the response with correct answer. How can I get all @PhilW?

Comment: If you want all, you need to ensure that "options" is an array, then you need to make sure you instantiate new option entries as you go and add them to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `emailOptions` at the beginning of your method (a new `EmailOptionAttributes`) but are not doing anything with it, as instead you're trying to access `wrapper.options` that is `null` at this point.

Instead, you can populate the properties of `emailOptions` and then assign this value to `wrapper`'s  options field.

Taking your `emailValidation` method into consideration, it would be somehow similar to:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void emailValidation(String email){
        EmailOptionAttributes emailOptions = new EmailOptionAttributes();
        EmailWrapper wrapper = new EmailWrapper();
        System.debug('email====-: ' +email);
        if(email != null){
            System.debug('email====-: ' +email);
            wrapper.emailValue = email;
            System.debug('email2====-: ' +email);
        }
        Email_validation__mdt[] emailValidation = [SELECT Field1__c,Field2__c,Field3__c,Field4__c,Field5__c FROM Email_validation__mdt];
        System.debug('emailValidation' +emailValidation);
        for (Email_validation__mdt threatMapping : emailValidation) {
            emailOptions.fieldOne = threatMapping.Field1__c;
            emailOptions.fieldTwo = threatMapping.Field2__c;
            emailOptions.fieldThree =  threatMapping.Field3__c;
            emailOptions.fieldFour = threatMapping.Field4__c;
            emailOptions.fieldFive = threatMapping.Field5__c;
        }
        wrapper.options = emailOptions;

        System.debug('emailOptions: ' +emailOptions);
        String jsonString = JSON.serialize(emailOptions);
        System.debug('jsonString: ' +jsonString);

    }
```

Best regards!